# Condition on $\sqrt{n}+\sqrt[3]{n}$

Tags: number-theory, radicals

Let $n \in \mathbb{Q}$ a number that respects:
$\sqrt{n}+\sqrt[3]{n} \in \mathbb{N}$.
What can we say about $n$?

My answer is that $n$ must be a perfect square, a perfect cube and an integer at the same time.
The problem is showing that $n=\frac{r^6}{q^6}$, because I think that I did it, but using a long way, so I'd like to know if there's a shorter way without many calculations.

Comment: I don't think that is what the OP is saying. OP has shown that $n=r^6/q^6$, and then shown the rest - that $q=1$. But OP is wondering if there is an easy way to show $n=r^6/q^6$.

Comment: Thomas you are right

Comment: It's hard to know if our way is "simpler" if you don't show us what you have done....

Comment: My proof starts from: $\sqrt{n}+\sqrt[3]{n}=k$. Squaring both side  and always keeping in RHS a rational number I find at first $(4\sqrt{[3]{n}+6\sqrt[6]{n}) \in \mathbb{Q}$, and after other similar manipulations $(256 \sqrt{[3]{n} +192 \sqrt[6]{n} ) \in \mathbb{Q}$. Combining two result i obtain $\sqrt[3]{n} \in \mathbb{Q}$ and so it's done.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If $\sqrt{n} + \sqrt[3]{n} = m$, then $\sqrt{n} = m - \sqrt[3]{n}$. Squaring both sides yields

$$\begin{equation} \tag{$\ast$} \sqrt[3]{n}^2 - 2m \sqrt[3]{n} + m^2 - n = 0. \end{equation}$$

Now if $n$ is not a cube of a rational number, the polynomial $x^3 - n$ does not have any rational roots, so it is irreducible over $\mathbb{Q}$ (since any factorization would involve a factor of degree one). Thus $\left[ \mathbb{Q} \big[ \sqrt[3]{n} \big] : \mathbb{Q} \right] = 3$, so $(\ast)$ may not hold. Hence $n$ is a cube of a rational number.

Now $\sqrt{n} = m - \sqrt[3]{n}$ is rational, so $n$ is also a square of a rational number, therefore $n = a^6$ for some $a \in \mathbb{Q}$.

---

**Edit:** since my solution involves some field theory the reader may be unfamiliar with, I will introduce the necessary part below.

Let $\mathbb{Q}[x]$ stand for the set of all polynomials with rational coeffiecients.

**Claim.** Let $n \in \mathbb{Q}$ and $\alpha = \sqrt[3]{n}$. Suppose the polynomial $p(x) = x^3 - n$ is irreducible over $\mathbb{Q}$, that is, whenever $p(x) \equiv u(x) \cdot v(x)$ for some $u(x), v(x) \in \mathbb{Q}[x]$, either $u(x)$ or $v(x)$ is constant. Then there is no nonzero polynomial $q(x) \in \mathbb{Q}[x]$ of degree at most $2$ such that $q(\alpha) = 0$.

**Proof.** Suppose that $q(\alpha) = 0$ fo some nonzero polynomial $q(x) \in \mathbb{Q}[x]$ of degree at most $2$. By polynomial division we find $u(x), r(x) \in \mathbb{Q}[x]$ such that $r(x) \equiv 0$ or $\deg r(x) < 2$ and

$$p(x) \equiv u(x) \cdot q(x) + r(x).$$

Substituting $x = \alpha$, we get

$$0 = u(\alpha) \cdot 0 + r(\alpha),$$

i.e. $r(\alpha) = 0$.

- If $r(x) \equiv 0$, we get a contradiction, because $p(x) \equiv u(x) \cdot q(x)$ is a factorization of $p(x)$ over $\mathbb{Q}$ with non-constant factors.
- If $\deg r(x) = 0$ so $r(x)$ is constant nonzero, this is an immediate contradiction.
- If $\deg r(x) = 1$, then $r(\alpha) = 0$ implies $\alpha \in \mathbb{Q}$ so $p(x)$ may be reduced by the factor $x-\alpha$, which is a contradiction.

So the claim is proved. $\blacksquare$

Now it suffices to note that $(\ast)$ may be written in form $q(\alpha) = 0$, where

$$q(x) = x^2 - 2mx + m^2 - n$$

has rational coefficients and degree $2$.

Comment: No, $\sqrt{1/64}+\sqrt[3]{1/64}\notin\mathbb N$ though $1/64=(1/2)^6$.

Comment: I don't know what $\left[ \mathbb{Q} \big[ \sqrt[3]{n} \big] : \mathbb{Q} \right] = 3$ mean. Can you explain, please?

Comment: @YvesDaoust But my claim goes in the other direction: if $\sqrt{n} + \sqrt[3]{n} \in \mathbb{N}$, then $n$ is a sixth power of a rational.

Comment: Ok, just a necessary condition then.

Comment: @L.A. It denotes the [degree of the field extension](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Degree_of_a_field_extension) $\mathbb{Q} \subseteq \mathbb{Q} \big[ \sqrt[3]{n} \big]$ i.e. we treat $\mathbb{Q} \big[ \sqrt[3]{n} \big]$ as a linear space over $\mathbb{Q}$ and compute the dimension. From $\left[ \mathbb{Q} \big[ \sqrt[3]{n} \big] : \mathbb{Q} \right] = 3$ we have that $1, \sqrt[3]{n}, \sqrt[3]{n}^2$ are linearly independent over $\mathbb{Q}$, so they can't satisfy a non-trivial equation like $(\ast)$. If the theory is unfamiliar to you, I may prove the relevant facts in my answer.